# flex 4.5 programmatically select tabnavigator by id

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, tabnavigator

Is there a way to programmatically select the tab displayed in the tabnavigator by using id instead of selectedIndex?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  Use the following code:

```
tb_all.selectedIndex = tb_all.getChildIndex(tb_calendar);
```